# Perfect powers on genus 0 curves (with restrictions)

Tags: nt.number-theory

I suppose a conjecture implies this so there might be an unconditional proof.

Let $F(x,y)=0$ be a curve with infinitely many integral points $(u^m,v^n)$ where
$\gcd(u,v)=1$ infinitely often and $m \ge 3,n \ge 2$.
Such curves are easy to construct by starting with a parametrization for example.

For a bivariate polynomial $F$ define $\operatorname{High}(F)$ to be the sum of
the highest degree monomials (i.e., $\operatorname{High}(F) = F$ iff $F$ is homogeneous and $\operatorname{High}(2x^3+3y^3+x+y)=2x^3+3y^3$).
Let $\gcd(\operatorname{High}(F),xy)=1$.

> Under these conditions is $\operatorname{High}(F)$ not square-free?
>
> Counterexamples?

This can't be relaxed to $m \ge 2 $

Answer (score 5):

(*Added some remarks from my comments*)

Suppose that $F=F_1F_2\cdots F_r$ with $F_i$ irreducible. If $F=0$ has infinitely many points of the requested form, then so does one of the factors. Furthermore, $\text{High}(F)=\text{High}(F_1)
\text{High}(F_2)\cdots\text{High}(F_r)$. So in order to look at the question, we may assume that $F$ is irreducible. But the $F$ is even absolutely irreducible, which we assume from now on.

As $F(x,y)=0$ has infinitely many integral solutions, then by Siegel's Theorem the projective closure of this curve has at most $2$ points at infinity. These point are just those with coordinates $(x:y:0)$ with $H(x,y)=0$, where $H=\text{High}(F)$. So the polynomial $H$ has total degree at most $2$ if it is to be separable and not divisible by $x$ nor $y$.

So a counterexample (that is where $H(x,y)$ is not squarefree) would have degree at most $2$.

I believe that degree $2$ can be ruled out. However, degree $1$ seems to amount to solve [Pillai's conjecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan%27s_conjecture): Given nonzero integers $A,B,C$, then $Au^m+Bv^n=C$ has only finitely many integral solutions $u,v,m,n$ with $m,n\ge3$. You have the additional assumption that $u$ and $v$ are relatively prime. I'm sure that this doesn't make the conjecture easier.

Comment: You don't use the hypothesis about perfect powers and in particular $m \ge 3$? You don't need this hypothesis to answer the question?

Comment: You don't mention coprimality at all. You don't need it to answer the question?

Comment: @joro: Indeed, it doesn't seem to be necessary to use these additional assumptions in order to reduce to degree $2$ which is easy to handle.

Comment: Hm, isn't $x^n-y^n=0$ counterexample to your claim about degree 2?. Points are (t,t). High(x^n-y^n)=x^n-y^n, the degree is n and it is squarefree?

Comment: Well, but this curve contains a straight line. Trivial examples like this are always possible. However, as your function $\text{High}$ is multiplicative, your question only makes sense for irreducible polynomials.

Comment: I suppose you assume genus 0 of the curve? What about curves for which CASes return negative genus (maybe singular and others) yet the curves have infinitely many integral points?

Comment: @joro: I guess a CAS might return a negative genus if the curve is not absolutely irreducible. If the curve nevertheless is irreducible, then there are only finitely many points on it. So when reducing to irreducible, you in addition may assume that the curve is absolutely irreducible.

Comment: It is more clear to me after the remarks, thanks.